# can i use VaderSentiment to calculate polarity and subjectivity on language other than English?

Tags: python, nlp, sentiment-analysis

i am trying to create a nlp project that calculate the polarity and subjectivity for texts that are not English so i can use 2 tools: **Vader** - **Textblob**.

After i done a lot of researches i found that Vader is more efficient and accurate for social media.

My question is : can i add language to vader in order to calculate socres?
 or is their a package for vader like multilanguage?

For the project i read from csv file and import it to dataframe pandas than pre-process and clean the text  than analyse it to extract the sentiments.

i will appreciate any help.

Comment: Do you have any link to that software?

Comment: what software ? you mean  the tools ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/cjhutto/vaderSentiment#resources-and-dataset-descriptions), Vader uses two resources:

1. a dictionary of tokens with their sentiment ratings
2. a set of syntactic rules that define the relationships between words

While you can create your own resources for other languages, but the authors state that

> Manually creating (much less, validating) a comprehensive sentiment lexicon is a labor intensive and sometimes error prone process

So while possible, it won't be easy. The lexicon file that comes with Vader comprises just shy of 8000 entries. I don't know how easy it is to generate these: presumably there is a trade-off between quickly achieving broad coverage and accuracy of the results. Perhaps you can go for coverage first, and then gradually improve accuracy by modifying the entries accordingly.

The syntactic rules (from a cursory glance) mainly seem to describe adverbs, and whether they increase or decrease the sentiment. Again, this is something that would have to be adjusted, as it's hard-coded for English in the source file. It depends how different your target language is grammatically from English how easy or difficult that task will be.

Comment: thank you for your answer. so short answer is NO but.   it can be done  with high range of errors.
so i will try **textblob** as it has multi-languages accessibility

Comment: I don't know what the accuracy will be; it very much depends on your data. But it seems quite some effort is required to get started in a different language.